# findOneAndUpdate returns null with client side

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, react-redux, mongodb-query, axios

I'm new to mongodb and mongoose.

I have this request that works perfectly on postman (update number of reservation)

```
  router.put("/book/:idEvent", (req, res) => {

  const _idEvent = req.params.idEvent;
  const places = req.body.places;

  Event.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: _idEvent },
    {
      $set: { places },
    },
    {new:true, upsert:true},
  )
    .then((event) => res.json(event))
    .catch((err) => res.json(err));
});
```

But when I call this on the client side, it insert null into attribute places.
According to mongodb documentation, it shouldn't be null when upsert&new properties are true,
I tried it but nothing changed.
I tried to send static arguments from the client side but it still returns null.
my frontend method:

```
   export const updatePlaces = (idEvent, updatedPlaces) =>  (dispatch) => {
   axios
    .put(`http://localhost:5000/events/book/${idEvent}`, updatedPlaces)
    .then((res) => dispatch(getEvents()))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

i learned also that the templateId is being sent via Xhr request from the client-side and sending information using Xhr (or any Ajax-type request) converts everything to 'string': so I changed the attribute type in schema from Number to String but again it returns null.

`places: { type: String},`

Any idea how to solve this problem??

Comment: Could you confirm that updatedPlaces is an object that looks like this: `{ places: value }`. Maybe `console.log(updatedPlaces)` before calling your `updatePlaces`  function.

Comment: I test with static values ​​and it always returns null

Comment: So `axios.put(url, { places: "1" } )` is not working? What happens if you test it in the backend like. `const places = { places: "1" } ` instead of `const places = req.body.places;`?

Comment: Wait, returns null. Your function `updatePlaces` will always return null. You are not returning anything in that function but instead you are triggering a dispatch action. Is that the problem? Have you checked your database, does the value update there?

Comment: my attribute in schema is defined like this: `places: {type: Number, default: 0}` so i test it with `const places = { places: 1 }` and it return `Cast to Number failed for value \"{ places: 1 }\" at path \"places\"",`

Comment: So first of all you are working with JSON and JSON can handle both numbers and string values. If you are sending a JSON object via axios,  it will not mess with your types. If you are unsure if your frontend gives you are string (e.g. input field) or a number, just use `Number.parseInt(places, 10)` in your backend to parse the string to a number. Also, make sure to drop the database table when changing the schema to be double sure. I think you should run it again after that and tell us the exact error message that you receive.

Comment: always the same result null

Comment: mh please try to be more concrete. What is null? The function return value? The result of the getPlaces() call? The actual database entry? Does mongoose throw any errors?

Comment: after executing the `updatePlaces` function, `places` attribute changes to null in the database and no error is thrown....
I think my problem comes from the request which changes the value passed in arguments before it arrives at the database or else mongodb change it...
I am not an expert

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your postman request, you assign `const places` to `req.body.places`:

```
 router.put("/book/:idEvent", (req, res) => {

  const _idEvent = req.params.idEvent;
  const places = req.body.places;
```

but in your client side code, you pass `updatedPlaces` to your request:

```
export const updatePlaces = (idEvent, updatedPlaces) =>  (dispatch) => {
   axios
    .put(`http://localhost:5000/events/book/${idEvent}`, updatedPlaces)
    .then((res) => dispatch(getEvents()))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

have you tried assigning `const places` to `req.body.updatedPlaces`?

Comment: updatedPlaces is just a variable name. It contains the request body. What is important is that `updatedPlaces = { places: rightType }`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the final solution but try this as a next step to debug your problem:

```
  router.put("/book/:idEvent", async (req, res) => {

  const _idEvent = req.params.idEvent;
  const places = req.body.places;

  const event = await Event.findOneById(_idEvent):

  if(!event) {
     console.log("event not found", _idEvent);
     // do your upsert logic here
     return;
  }

  // this code is for debugging
  if(!places) {
     throw Error("You never passed a places value in the first place!")
  }

  const placesVal = Number.parseInt(places, 10);
  if(Number.isNaN(placesVal)) {
      throw Error("Not a valid number", placesVal)
  }
  event.places = placesVal;
  const result = await event.save();
  res.json(result);
});
```